# SymPy substition with scalars doesn't work?

Tags: python, substitution, sympy

```
from sympy import *

x,y,s = symbols('xys')

z = (1 - 2*x*x)
w = (1 + 2*x*x)
q = 2*x*x*2*y*y

sub = {2*x*x: s}
print w.subs(sub)
print z.subs(sub)

print q
print q.subs(sub)
```

The output I get:

```
1 + s
1 - 2*x**2
4*x**2*y**2
4*x**2*y**2
```

The output I expect:

```
1 + s
1 - s
4*x**2*y**2
2*y**2*s
```

Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy seems to be inconsistent in what it matches. For instance, changing the sign on the matching substitution expression allows z to be matched with. I would consider adding this example to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=1520). I would also try the [Sympy mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/sympy). Remember, this project isn't even to version number 1.0 yet so things aren't going to be perfect just yet with it (or probably ever as with any software).

Comment: I have already noticed that changing sign makes it work in the second case instead of the first. It appears that scalar values are handled in a bit too direct way.
Also I know that this project is in a very early development stage and that symbolic operations are not easy, so it may be there for a very long time.
I was just hoping that this might be an easy enough problem to have some simple solution.
And I have already sent this example to the mailing list.